# Implementing Google Analytics in iOS App, if Firebase is already integrated for Push Notifications

Tags: objective-c, swift, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am having an iOS App in which Firebase is already integrated for the purpose of Push Notifications. So, I am having a GoogleService-Info.Plist file at the root of my target.

Now, I am adding Google Analytics SDK through pods and the tutorial is asking me to download another GoogleService-Info.plist file which is having a tracking ID. So, I am confused now that how to use Google Analytics in this case as I am already having a plist file.

I want to use google analytics as I want to do screen tracking which is not that efficient in FireBase Analytics.

Please can anybody guide me through the process of integrating Google Analytics when Firebase is already present in the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you with a common tutorial online [FireBase Analytics Docs.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseanalytics/api/reference/Classes/FIRAnalytics)
Use these docs to follow along in a tutorial that firebase has. For what I know about firebase is almost all the tutorials and help are written in swift and is kinda annoying if your writing in objective-c like I do. There is also sample projects on their website so it might be helpful to start at a sample project and work from there.